# C pointers instead of union

Tags: c, pointers, unions

I have an embedded system that should store different sets of results based on its state.

One possible solution is to use a union:

```
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        struct 
        {
            double  Val1;
            double  Val2;
        } State1;

        struct
        {
            double  Val3;
        } State2;
    };
} strBuf;
strBuf Buf;
```

Now I can store the values using these functions (which I can call by its function pointers to switch the type of measurement):

```
void meas1(strRes* res)
{
    Buf.State1.Val1 = res->v1;
    Buf.State1.Val2 = res->v2;
}

void meas2(strRes* res)
{
    Buf.State2.Val3 = res->v1;
}
```

The idea is to use either State1 or State2 based on the measurement.

I think the union struct is a solid way because I can not make mistakes when allocating the memory.
The down side is the unnecessary usage of the memory when in State2.
Another disadvantage is the possibility to access the wrong variable.

But just out of curiosity: How would I do that with pointers?
And what are the pros and cons of your suggested solution?

Edit:

The system generates values every 100 ms. These are beeing processed on an RX210.

The first state calculates from two doubles d1[n], d2[n] and it previous values d1[n-1], d2[n-1] the following:
m = log2(d1[n]/d1[n-1]) / log2(d2[n]/d2[n-1])
(I suppose log2 is the fastest log)

The second state only calculates the ratio of two doubles:
p = d1[n]/d2[n]

This means I don't have to store the n-1 values.

Edit 2:
strRes is the pointer to the values genereated before. Something like

```
typedef struct 
{
    double v1;
    double v2;
} strRes;
```

Comment: At most basic level you would have `void*` pointers holding addresses to structs of varied types. More complex form might be using structs within structs to mimick inheritance. Your question is quite vague and as such it is unclear how you expect your problem to be solved.

Comment: What's `strRes` here?

Comment: @ Lưu Vĩnh Phúc strRes is a pointer to the measured values which contains either a voltage and a current (both as double) or two voltages (as double).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code.

```
typedef struct {
    double *val;
} strBuf;
strBuf Buf;

void meas1(strRes* res)
{
    Buf.val = malloc(2 * sizeof(double));
    Buf.val[0] = res->v1;
    Buf.val[1] = res->v2;
}

void meas2(strRes* res)
{
    Buf.val = malloc(1 * sizeof(double));
    Buf.val[0] = res->v1;
}
```

Pros: Memory allocated dynamically as and when needed.
No unnecessary wastage of memory.

cons: Speed, as memory is allocated at run time.

Comment: Memory wastage is debatable. You need extra pointer and possible overhead of `malloc`. But that is more of a problem with unclear question than your answer.

Comment: The information of where dynamic memory is stored and how large the segment is, has to be stored somewhere. It all seems like "pre-mature optimization" to me.

Comment: @user694733 : W.r.t the memory wastage, it still consumes the same memory except that when scaling there is a difference. I agree with you on this as this is debatable. Same with `malloc` and `free` extra overhead.

Comment: @Lundin: Is the information of where dynamic memory stored required ? This answer was to give an hint or an overview for OP to take a clue and extrapolate. More generic code or how large the segment is left to OP.